# Erros in fastify lib using ajv

Tags: typescript, fastify

I receieve this errors when i build my typescript code

node_modules/@fastify/ajv-compiler/types/index.d.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"ajv"' has no exported member 'AnySchema'.
node_modules/@fastify/ajv-compiler/types/index.d.ts(6,12): error TS2709: Cannot use namespace '_ajv' as a type.

idk what to do to fix it

"fastify": "^4.24.3"
"typescript": "^5.2.2"

Comment: have you tried installing `ajv` as a separate dependency?

Comment: you can use `skipLibCheck` in tsconfig.json to ignore problems inside libraries

Comment: `strict: true` + `esModuleInterop: true` in tsconfig.json might do the trick too

Comment: @Meowster i remove the entry "node_modules" from "paths" in my tsconfig.json... seems it works... ty.

Answer (score 0):

i just remove the entry "node_modules" from "paths" in my tsconfig.json... seems it works...